# Postorder and Preorder traversal on a Binary tree

Tags: trees

For the tree below, list the labels of the nodes of the tree according to the pre-ordering algorithm, and then re-list them according to the post-ordering algorithm.

```
                                    1
                                   / \
                                  2   3
                                 / \   \ 
                                4   5   6
                               / \     / \
                              7   8   9   10
```

---

Is my attempt correct I always get confused between the traversal methods:

Pre-ordering: 1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 10

Post-ordering: 7, 8, 4, 5, 2, 9, 10, 6, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good; you just made a couple errors. The pre-order traversal should be:
$$
1, 2, 4, 7, \color{red}8, \color{red}5, 3, 6, 9, 10
$$
and the post-order should finish at the root, $1$.

Comment: Ok so you take the bottom right branch in situations like that.

Comment: Thanks I forgot about that root

Comment: Yes. For the tree rooted at $2$, all nodes in the left subtree (namely, $4,7,8$) should be traversed before all nodes in the right subtree (namely, $5$).

Comment: Nice explanation I was not thinking in terms of sub-trees.